# What is variable scope of routes.rb in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got simple question:
What is the variable scope within *routes.rb* in Rails. 
To be more specific : 
Can I refer to *ApplicationController*'s variables in this particular file ? Just like in views ?

I'm asking, because I cannot get this lambda to work :

```
root to: "users#edit", constraints: lambda { |req| !@current_user.nil? }, as: :authenticated_root
```

@current_user is declared in module included in application_controller.rb, but it is not visible in *routes.rb*

Presumably, I'm overlooking some important page in manual...

Comment: _Can I refer to `ApplicationController`'s variables in this particular file?_ Answer: __no, you can't__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, route constraints do not have access to variables set within the controller.

You really should move your logic to the controller in a `before_action` (>= Rails 4) or `before_filter` (<= Rails 3.2).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to avoid... I know there is devise, but I'm such a human being wanted to reinvent the wheel on almost every step...

Comment: @Gobol Why do you want to avoid that? You typically want for your controller to redirect to a login form if the user is not authenticated. If you deny access to the route entirely, then that's not even an option anymore.

Comment: @Gobol Also, consider looking at Warden for authentication if you don't want something as bloated as Devise.